# How to Retrieve the User Defined Objects from Collection of Collections Object

Tags: java

In one of my requirment i have a key and each key associated with multiple document objects
            these i am storing in to HashMap with key and value pair .Key is the id and values is the List of 
            documents associated with that kEY

```
        Ex : HashMap<String,List<Document>> 

        I want to put all the list documents in one collection object , ie.List<Documents> (all documents of all keys)
        When i am using values() method of Hashmap i am getting Collection<List<Document>>

        If i want to get all the document objects i have to get each List<Document> ,iterate and add it into new collection object.

        other than this Is there any best way i can get all the Documents one at a time in collection Object.
        using any apache common-collections or apache commons-collections4 api ?


        ArrayList<Document> al = new ArrayList<Document>();
        Document dto1 = new Document();
        dto1.setResearchId("1");
        dto1.setIsinCode("isinCode1");
        dto1.setEquity("equity1");

        Document dto2 = new Document();
        dto2.setResearchId("2");
        dto2.setIsinCode("isinCode2");
        dto2.setEquity("equity2");

        Document dto3 = new Document();
        dto3.setResearchId("3");
        dto3.setIsinCode("isinCode3");
        dto3.setEquity("equity3");

        Document dto4 = new Document();
        dto4.setResearchId("4");
        dto4.setIsinCode("isinCode4");
        dto4.setEquity("equity4");

        al.add(dto1);
        al.add(dto2);
        al.add(dto3);
        al.add(dto4);

        Map<String ,List<Document>> mapList = 
                 new HashMap<String,List<Document>>();
        mapList.put("1", al);
        mapList.put("2", al);
        mapList.put("3", al);


      Excepted output : Collection<Document>

       For sample i have added the same arraylist object in to my Map 
       but in actual i will have different arrayList objects.
```

Comment: Could you show example code? It will be easier to follow what you want. And it would be nice to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to flatten the `List`s in the `Map`'s values to a single collection. Java 8 allows you do this pretty easily:

```
List<Document> flatDocuments = // could also be defined as a Collection<Document>
    mapList.values()
           .stream()
           .flatMap(Collection::stream)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, if you just want to do something with them (such as printing them), you can skip the collecting phase and operate on them directly using `forEach`:

```
mapList.values()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**EDIT:**

For older Java versions you'd have to implement the same logic yourself using loops (or, of course, use some third party that does it for you):

```
List<Document> flatDocuments = new LinkedList<>();
for (List<Document> list : mapList.values()) {
    flatDocuments.addAll(list);
}
```

Comment: we are using JDK 7 , not 8

Comment: @Maddy I highly recommend upgrading to Java 8. Regardless, in this case, the streams API is just a nicety, and you could accomplish the same behavior yourself by iterating over the `values()` collection. I've edited my answer with an example of how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're suggesting apache commons-collections4 yourself, did you actually look at it?

The [`values()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html#values()) method of the [`MultiValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) does exactly what you want.

> **`Collection<V> values()`**
>
> Gets a `Collection` view of all values contained in this multi-valued map.
>
> Implementations typically return a collection containing the combination of values from all keys.